# If $((p-1)*(q-1) -1)$ divisible by $e$ ($e$ is odd number) , then $\text{gcd}(e,(p-1)*(q-1)) = 1$

Tags: rsa, prime-numbers

If $((p-1)(q-1) -1)$ divisible by $e$ ($e$ is odd number) , then $\text{gcd}(e,(p-1)(q-1)) = 1$. ($p,q$ are prime numbers ) Is this true, if yes why, if not why not ?

Comment: Hint: use the first one to form a [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) and use the [converse case](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1279900/338051)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this true?

I'd generalize it, and replace $(p-1)(q-1)$ with $X$; that is, if $X-1$ is divisible by $e$, that is, if $X-1 = k \times e$ for some integer $k$, then $\gcd(e, X) = 1$. Is this true?  If it is, then your original statement is also true (because if it holds for all $X, e$, it also holds for all $X$ that is of the form $(p-1)(q-1)$ and for all odd $e$.).

As a further hint, we can also observe that $\gcd(e, X) = \gcd(e, X \bmod e)$ (that's the central observation that makes the Euclidean method for evaluating $\gcd$ work).

With that, it should be fairly straight-forward to proceed...

Comment: Yeah thank you e must be selected such that gcd(e,X) = 1 so the first part can hold. This is similar to RSA algorithm, we select e such that gcd(e,phi(n)) = 1. So question that i took this was : Prove this cryptosystem is equivalent to RSA : 1: Select an odd number e, 2: choose two primes p,q such that (p-1)(q-1) -1 is divisible by e. 3: Calculate N= p*q. 4: Calculate d = ((p-1)(q-1)(e-1) + 1)/e